# How to distribute XML schema definitions (XSD)

Tags: xml, xsd

I am curious about what are considered best practices when it comes to distributing XML schemas.

In my particular situation, I have a webservice which accepts an XML file that must conform to an XSD that I have defined.  I am thinking of distributing the XSD to clients via a complimentary webservice that can be invoked at any time.

Please share any ideas or ways that you have distributed XSD's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://schemas.opengis.net:

- Make sure your schemas are valid like angel's feathers.
- Make your schemas accessible via web. HTTP first of all. No "please accept this license first" disclaimer.
- Make sure your schemas use only relative URLs referring to one another.
- Assemble a downloadable package (ZIP) with your schemas.

Many people will want to access your schemas online. Some will want to put your schemas into their software - to be able to validate against these schemas offline/without depending on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the XSD on a web server, so people and programs can easily access it using plain HTTP. There's no need to write a web service for that. Put the link to the XSD into your manual / documentation, and everybody can use it.